# iOS8 UISplitViewController in PrimaryOverlay mode, not AllVisible

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

I am building an iPad only/landscape only app in iOS 8 and want to take advantage of the new features are available in the UISplitViewController, in that I want to create a collapsable primary controller that can disappear when I need a fullscreen detail view.

I am using the basic storyboard with a Container VC containing my splitVC...

[image]

I am using this code to achieve that function...

```
import UIKit

class ContainerViewController: UIViewController, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let splitViewController = self.childViewControllers[0] as UISplitViewController
        splitViewController.delegate = self

        splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = .AllVisible

        let navViewController = splitViewController.childViewControllers.last as UINavigationController
        navViewController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem();
    }

    func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController!, collapseSecondaryViewController secondaryViewController:UIViewController!, ontoPrimaryViewController primaryViewController:UIViewController!) -> Bool {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note I am using .*AllVisible* as the preferred display mode. This works except my detail view is pushed to the right when I show the primary view.

What I'd actually like to do is use the Preferred display mode of .*PrimaryOverlay* which 'should' overlay the primary on the secondary. It does, but is incorrect size and misplaced on the initial showing of the controllers. The first time the display appears, I get this effect....

[image]

... and after tapping to hide/reshow the system seems to sort itself and the primary is properly overlaid onto the secondary...

[image]

Can anyone help so this works initially as expected?